# converting String XML to SoapMessage

Tags: java, soap

I am trying to convert string xml into soapMessage using below code,

```
 System.out.println("response:" + response.toString());
                 InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.toString().getBytes());
                 SOAPMessage responseSoap = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL).createMessage(null, is);
                 System.out.println("body "+responseSoap.getSOAPBody());
                 System.out.println("1");
                 QName bodyName = new QName("Response");
                  SOAPBody sb = responseSoap.getSOAPBody();
                  System.out.println("2");
                  Iterator iterator = sb.getChildElements(bodyName);
                  System.out.println("entered into SoapResponse 3");
                  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                      System.out.println("entered into SoapResponse 4");
                    SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = (SOAPBodyElement) iterator.next();
                    String val = bodyElement.getValue();
                    System.out.println("The Value is:" + val);
                  }
```

It printing,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><Response xmlns="http://service.com/integration/"><Result xsi:type="LoginResponse"><UserId>12</UserId><TypeId>1</TypeId><Success>true</Success></Result></Response></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

body [soap:Body: null]
```

why I am getting body null?

Answer (score 1):

The `toString()` implementation of `SoapBody` returns `"["+getNodeName()+": "+getNodeValue()+"]";`. This is implemented in `NodeImpl.java` which is an implementation of `SoapBody` super class `Node`. In your case the `getNodeValue()` is null.

If your requirement is to print the response, you can do `responseSoap.writeTo(System.out);`.

You may also want to replace

```java
QName bodyName = new QName("Response");
```

with

```java
QName bodyName = new QName("http://service.com/integration/", "Response");
```

Also use `String val = bodyElement.getTextContent();` if it makes sense for your use case. `getValue` is for Text nodes.

Comment: now I am getting The Value is:121true, but need to get value based on tageName like int userId = bodyElement.getTageName("UserId");

Comment: You will have to use `getElementsByTagName`. Refer to documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName(java.lang.String)